# Методы для строк

Tags: java

У меня есть допустим 3 строки

```
3424    Alex   432424
3244    John   432423
2342    Kate   432423
```

Я хочу, чтобы в значение строки записывалось чистое имя без цифр и пробелов, как мне это реализовать?
мне надо это сделать, не писав каких-то find("Alex"), на месте тех имен у много разных, мне нужно т.е записывать ту строку, которая находится между пробелами

Answer (score 0):

Каждый раз, когда вы считываете новую строку, используйте метод `split` по пробелу и выводите второй элемент массива. Пример кода:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    String line = in.next();
    if (line.equals("")) 
        break;
    String[] parts = line.trim().split(" ");
    if (parts.length > 1) 
        System.out.println(parts[1]);
}
```

Метод `trim()` отрезает пробелы слева и справа у входной строки.

Код может сработать в случае структурированного файла. Иначе у строки есть метод `matches`, который проверяет строку по регулярному выражению:

```
for (String s: line.trim().split(" ")) {
    if (s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+"))
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: не получается, у меня такая строка "4025 DvP d8578edf8458ce06fbc5bb76a58c5ca4 md5 0.00  214783447849792 -29e6909eb083e91cd15fd3ec6e96eb9392055927 maks-sova1970@yandex.ru 0 0   0 0 0"

Comment: То есть у вас имеется файл, который не содержит определённую структуру? Не колонками, как было показано в примере?

Comment: получается, что так

Comment: Попробуйте тогла метод `matches` :)